# Input value is undefined even when ng-model is defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have an AngularJS directive to show or hide input labels. Everything works fine when you start with an empty input and start typing. But when the input is pre-filled with ng-model the label should be shown initially, and it is starting hidden. I have checked the value of the input, and it is undefined. I'm sure there is an obvious reason/solution, but I cannot find it. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/x9Mgfwb6H6RoOScsLE2S)

ANGULAR:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.customer = {
    name: "Patrick"
  };
});

app.directive('labelToggle', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {

      var thisLabel = element.find('label');
      var thisInput = element.find('input');

      scope.valueDefined = thisInput[0].value;

      thisInput.on('keyup', function () {

        if (this.value) {
          thisLabel.addClass('show-label');
        } else {
          thisLabel.removeClass('show-label');
        }

        scope.valueDefined = thisInput[0].value;

      });

    }
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div label-toggle class="input-wrap">
  <label>Customer</label>
  <input type="text" name="customer" placeholder="Customer" ng-model="customer.name">
</div>

<div>Value? {{valueDefined}}</div>
```

As a side question that came up when writing the Plunker, why is the scope update happening one keypress behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Way simplified solution is to just use ng-class instead

http://plnkr.co/edit/aqYHWtzhilWrU2YpTscx?p=preview

```
  <label ng-class="{'show-label':customer.name}">Customer</label>
```

Regarding why your code isn't working, the model likely hasn't updated when the key down event occurs (doesn't work with keyup either I tried) but if you want to know what's going on with the ng-model for an input you probably want to look at ngModelController to see how you can require ng-model and get a handle on when the value is updated or trigger changes if needed.

Alternatively when you just want to call some function in a controller when a model changes use ng-change.

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I made that so much more complicated than it needed to be. Thanks.

Comment: @psnoonan yeah I did that a lot when first learning angular too, learned about directives and started trying to write them for everything but really there is a lot you can do with what's in the box before you need to start doing custom things, glad this works for ya though.

Answer (score 0):

As you guessed, it is a pretty obvious solution once you see it.

You've bound an event listener to the `keyup` event from the input field.
Until the `keyup` event fires `valueDefined` will be undefined because it's only ever defined in one place (inside the event listener function).
The text output is pointing to `{{valueDefined}}` rather than the ng-model value.

"why is the scope update happening one keypress behind?" ^^ See above. This is all triggered by a keypress on that input field.

As shaunhusain mentions, you can achieve this with ng-class. There isn't actually a need for a new directive here.